# C memcpy causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, memcpy, memory-pool

So I'm trying to implement a simple memory pool as part of an assignment for University however I've ran in to trouble with storing values inside the memory I have allocated.

This is my main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Pool.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Pool* pool = allocate_pool(64);

    printf("Pool Size: %d bytes...\n", pool->size_bytes);

    int* a = (int*)100;

    store_in_pool(pool, 20, sizeof(int), a);

    void* ap = retrieve_from_pool(pool, 20, sizeof(int));

    printf("%d\n", ap);

    free_pool(pool);

    return 0;
}
```

My Pool.h file:

```
#ifndef ASSIGNMENT_2_POOL_H
#define ASSIGNMENT_2_POOL_H

typedef struct MemoryPool
{
    int size_bytes;
    void* data;
} Pool;

Pool* allocate_pool(int size_bytes);
void  free_pool(Pool* pool);
void  store_in_pool(Pool* pool, int offset_bytes, int size_bytes, void* object);
void* retrieve_from_pool(Pool* pool, int offset_bytes, int size_bytes);

#endif
```

And my Pool.c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Pool.h"

Pool* allocate_pool(int size_bytes)
{
    Pool* pool = (Pool*)malloc(sizeof(Pool*));
    pool->size_bytes = size_bytes;
    pool->data = malloc(size_bytes);

    int i = 0;
    while(i < pool->size_bytes)
    {
        void* temp = (int*)pool->data + i++;
        temp = 0;
    }

    return pool;
}

void free_pool(Pool* pool)
{
    free(pool->data);
    free(pool);
}

void store_in_pool(Pool* pool, int offset_bytes, int size_bytes, void* object)
{
    memcpy((void*)((char*)pool->data + offset_bytes), object, size_bytes);
}

void* retrieve_from_pool(Pool* pool, int offset_bytes, int size_bytes)
{
    return (void*)((char*)pool->data + offset_bytes);
}
```

The issue appears whenever I call 'store_in_pool' which contains a line that calls memcpy. I'm not sure what the issue is as I'm certain I'm passing the correct values to the function however a segmentation fault occurs every time I try and run the program.

What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I've always thought the `type *x = malloc(sizeof(*x))`-idiom to be rather ugly, but considering *how many* people here seem to get this wrong, it may be necessary...

Comment: @EOF I thought  the received wisdom from this site was to refer the size of the variable pointed to, not its type, being more easily maintainable.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Well, it doesn't *look* right to me. I find `T *x = malloc(sizeof(T))` *nicer* than `T *x = malloc(sizeof(*x))`, but yeah, I've see *a lot* of people get `malloc()` wrong recently...

Comment: Using a temp var, eg 'int poolUnitSize=sizeof(thingyWotsit);',and use of your debugger to step through, would have revealed the error.

Comment: @EOF do you mind explaining what's wrong with said statement? Changing the line to 'Pool *pool = malloc(sizeof(Pool))' doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @LiamPotter: I *would* mind, because that sort of thing should be covered by any beginner's c-tutorial or course. I'm not going to fix every error in your code for you, because frankly there are more of them there than you can shake a stick at. For example, what do you think `int* a = (int*)100;` does for you?

Comment: What is that `while` loop supposed to be doing? If it's to initialize `pool->data` to all zeroes, it doesn't do that.

Comment: @Barmar: It causes undefined behavior is what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Pool* pool = (Pool*)malloc(sizeof(Pool*));
```

On 32 bit systems sizeof(Pool*)==4.  This is because the Pool* argument indicates that you want the size of a pointer to Pool.  Pointer sizes are constant (4 on 32 bit, 8 on 64 bit).  It should be:

```
Pool* pool = (Pool*)malloc(sizeof(Pool));
```

In this case the size of the the Pool struct will be sent to malloc.  One other thing I noticed in your code.  It's not a bug, per se, but it is code with zero effect:

```
while(i < pool->size_bytes)
{
    void* temp = (int*)pool->data + i++;
    temp = 0;
}
```

You are setting the temp pointer to NULL, essentially, not setting the variable to which it pointed to 0.  This means that your pool->data is never initialized.  One way to modify it:

```
while(i < pool->size_bytes)
{
    char* temp = (char*)pool->data + i++;
    *temp = 0;
}
```

Or simply:

```
memset(pool->data, 0, pool->size_bytes);
```

Or just catch it at the source and remove the initialization code if all you need is initialization to 0:

```
   pool->data = calloc(1, pool->size_bytes);
```

In this case, calloc sets all bytes to 0.

Comment: The first modification of the `while()`-loop you propose accesses out-of-bounds.

Comment: Consider that few c-implementations have `sizeof(int) == 1`.

Comment: @EOF  True.  That's what I get for editing out of context :^).  I fixed it with a sizeof.  Thanx for the quick eye, EOF.

Comment: @yapdog think! what if size_bytes is 7 ?  ;)

Comment: @gollum  HA!  In that case, he's all screwed up, isn't he?  After all, he's  initializing to ints ;^)

Comment: @yapdog +1 for proposing calloc and memset. However, if you try to fix his broken zeroing code at all you should also post a working alternative, e.g. one that does it byte per byte.

Comment: I had the wrong allocation; I meant to calloc the pool->data.  Fixed.  It's been a long morning....

Comment: @gollum  When you're right, you're right.  Fixed.  Wow, you guys are good.

Answer (score 2):

The segmentation fault is happening because of this:

```
int* a = (int*)100;
```

This sets `a` to be a pointer to the address `100`, which is not part of your accessible memory. So when you then try to copy from that address with `memcpy()`, you get a fault.

If you want `a` to point to an integer with the value `100`, the correct way is:

```
int aval = 100;
int *a = &aval;
```

You also need to fix the way you call `malloc()` in `allocate_pool`:

```
Pool* pool = malloc(sizeof Pool);
```

Your code is just allocating enough space for a pointer, not the entire `Pool` structure.

The `while` loop that looks like it's trying to initialize `data` to zero is also wrong. You can simply use `memset`:

```
memset(pool->data, 0, size_bytes);
```

You could also have used `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` to allocate the space, since it automatically initializes the space to zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Pool* pool = (Pool*)malloc(sizeof(Pool*));
```

to this:

```
Pool* pool = malloc(sizeof Pool);
```

Comment: The error still occurs after changing that line unfortunately.

Comment: Look at Barmar's answer too.  That's another problem